# Get filtered data from ui-grid in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is there any way we can get all the filtered data from ui-grid to controller to perform some processing. Intially i have 100 records, on applying some filter it gives 10 records, I need those 10 records in controller.

[image]

As shown in image I need only the filtered record. I need to use filtered value somewhere else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more stack overflow provided me answer

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, onFilterChanged);
},

$scope.filteredRows=[];
function onFilterChanged()
  {
    console.log('no arguments passed:', arguments)
    $scope.filtered = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows();
    console.log('grid filtered data', $scope.filtered)
  }
```

Thanks